Assembly x64: Issue with Function Calls and Stack Alignment in Assembler-Disassembler Tool on Windows
I'm working on an assembler-disassembler tool in x64 assembly on Windows, and I'm encountering a strange issue related to function calls and stack alignment. The program is supposed to support basic assembly instructions (MOV, ADD, SUB, JMP) and convert them into machine code. However, after implementing the core functionality, I ran into a problem where the program crashes or fails silently, especially after making certain function calls.
Code Overview:
Here's a simplified version of the code, focusing on the problematic areas:
section .data
    input_msg db "Enter assembly instruction: ", 0
    output_msg db "Machine code: ", 0
    invalid_msg db "Invalid instruction or operands!", 10, 0

    ; Opcode definitions and other data...

section .bss
    instruction resb 50     ; Buffer for user input
    opcode resb 5           ; Buffer for generated opcode
    op_len resd 1           ; Length of opcode
    operand1 resb 10        ; Buffer for operand1
    operand2 resb 10        ; Buffer for operand2

section .text
    extern printf, scanf, ExitProcess, sscanf, atoi, strcmp
    global main

main:
    sub rsp, 40

    lea rcx, [rel input_msg]
    call printf

    lea rcx, [rel fmt_string]
    lea rdx, [rel instruction]
    call scanf

    lea rcx, [rel instruction]
    lea rdx, [rel operand1]
    lea r8, [rel operand2]
    call parse_instruction

    cmp dword [rel op_len], 0
    je invalid_instruction

    lea rcx, [rel output_msg]
    call printf

    ; More code...

invalid_instruction:
    lea rcx, [rel invalid_msg]
    call printf
    add rsp, 40
    xor ecx, ecx
    call ExitProcess

parse_instruction:
    sub rsp, 32      ; Allocate shadow space

    ; Initialize op_len to 0
    mov dword [rel op_len], 0

    ; Extract operation and operands
    lea r9, [rel operand1]
    lea r10, [rel operand2]
    lea r11, [rel operation]
    lea rax, [rel fmt_string]
    mov rcx, rax
    mov rdx, r9
    mov r8, r10
    lea rax, [rel instruction]
    call sscanf_wrapper

    ; Compare operation
    lea rax, [rel operation]
    call str_compare_mov
    cmp al, 1
    je handle_mov

    call str_compare_add
    cmp al, 1
    je handle_add

    call str_compare_sub
    cmp al, 1
    je handle_sub

    call str_compare_jmp
    cmp al, 1
    je handle_jmp

    ; Invalid instruction
    jmp parse_end

handle_mov:
    ; MOV reg, imm
    ; opcode: 0xB8 + reg_code | imm (4 bytes)
    mov rdi, [rel operand1]
    call get_register_code
    cmp al, 0xFF
    je parse_end
    mov bl, [rel opcode_mov]
    add bl, al             ; opcode = 0xB8 + reg_code
    mov [rel opcode], bl
    ; Convert immediate value
    mov rdi, [rel operand2]
    call atoi_wrapper
    mov eax, [rel atoi_result]
    lea rbx, [rel opcode]
    mov [rbx + 1], eax
    mov dword [rel op_len], 5  ; 1 byte opcode + 4 bytes immediate
    jmp parse_end


Get the complete code from GitHub

The parse_instruction function is where the issue seems to occur. The function parses the input assembly instruction and generates the corresponding machine code. It performs string comparisons to determine the operation (MOV, ADD, SUB, JMP) and then generates the appropriate opcode.
Debugging Steps Taken:

Shadow Space Allocation: I allocated shadow space (32 bytes) for every function, as required by the Windows x64 calling convention. This didn’t resolve the issue.

Stack Alignment: I ensured that the stack is aligned properly before making any function calls. The main function aligns the stack by subtracting 40 bytes from rsp, and each function has its own shadow space allocation.

Simplified Function Calls: I reduced the complexity of the code by simplifying function calls and only focusing on the core functionality, but the issue persisted.

Removed/Isolated Functionality: I tried commenting out sections of the code and isolating specific functions to see if the issue was tied to a particular piece of logic. The program still failed after specific function calls, indicating that it’s not tied to one piece of logic.

Review Calling Conventions: I double-checked the Windows x64 calling convention requirements to ensure that registers are being used correctly and that the required shadow space is being allocated, but this did not fix the issue.


Specific Issue:
After all the above steps, the program still crashes or fails without producing the correct output. It seems related to the function calls and stack management, but I’m unable to pinpoint the exact cause.
Compile Environment and Steps:

OS: Windows 10 x64
Assembler: NASM
Linker: Mingw-w64
IDE: IntelliJ

Assemble:
nasm -f win64 ASM.asm -o ASM.o

Linking:
gcc -m64 -o ASM ASM.o -lkernel32 -lmsvcrt

Run the program:
.\ASM.exe

What I’m Looking For:
I'm seeking advice on:

Possible Causes: What could be causing this issue, given the debugging steps I've taken?
Best Practices: Are there best practices for handling stack alignment, shadow space, and function calls in x64 assembly on Windows that I might be overlooking?
Further Debugging Steps: What other steps can I take to debug or resolve this issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. I'm stuck and not sure what else to try at this point.

None of your functions except main aligns the stack properly. Everywhere else you only allocate shadow space. Change to 40 instead of 32 everywhere.

You wrote "Here's a version of the code focusing on the problematic areas" and "The parse_instruction function is where the issue seems to occur", but for some reason you didn't show that function.

My apologies for the confusion @prl. I updated the missing function :)

@Jester I tried to compile the program by fixing the shadow spaces correctly but the problem still occurs :/

Note also that your assembler needs to emit unwind codes for exception handling and stack walking purposes. If the system needs to walk the stack and the unwind codes are not present (or are wrong), it will terminate the process on the assumption that its stack is corrupted.

It's unclear how you want parse_instruction to work. The comment says that rcx - pointer to instruction string and you pass that in accordingly however the function does not use it and instead just overwrites with mov rcx, rax. You also set lea r11, [rel operation] but then don't use it. Your fmt_string is a single %s but you seem to expect it to parse into 3 parts.

@RaymondChen Thank you for the insight! I hadn't considered the need to emit unwind codes for exception handling and stack walking. I'll look into how to properly generate these codes in my assembler. This could indeed be causing the system to terminate the process due to perceived stack corruption.

@Jester Thanks to you! The use of rcx and lea r11, [rel operation] was a mistake on my part. I'll review how parse_instruction is intended to work and fix the code to correctly utilize rcx and r11. I'll also revisit the format string to ensure it parses as expected :)
